# Recursively find a string within a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, recursion, substring

(C++)
Given myString, I want to check if myString contains substring. Here's what I have so far, but it only returns true if the string begins with the substring.

```
 bool find(string myString, string substring)
{
    if(mystring.length() < substring.length())
    { 
        return false;
    }
    if(mystring == substring)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < substring.length() - 1 ; ++i)
    {
        if(mystring.at(i) == substring.at(i))
           {
               continue;
           }
        else
        {
            string string2 = mystring.substr(1, mystring.length() - 1);
            return find(string2, substring); 
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is wrong with this function?

Comment: Although it's fun to do it this way, you are taking a lot of value copies of the strings. You can do this without a single string copy, and in O(N), even if you want to search for multiple occurrences.

Comment: What I meant was, why doesn't the function work?

Comment: I know. I'm too old to step through this code, but (i) `substr` is zero based, and (ii) you're missing a `return`.

Comment: When you recursively check the substring 1 less character than the string you only check the substring removing the left most character but not the other possible substring removing the right most character.

Comment: How would I fix it? I don't think you can do double recursion...

Comment: Why are you using recursion?

Comment: As the OP already uses `substr` in the code, I'm sure this is just a way to learn more about recursion in general.

Comment: I fixed the code so it goes one character at a time. Somehow, it still does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the function can be written simpler. For example

```
bool find( const std::string &myString, const std::string &subString )
{
    return 
    ( myString.substr( 0, subString.size() ) == subString ) ||
    ( subString.size() < myString.size() && find( myString.substr( 1 ), subString ) );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool find( const std::string &myString, const std::string &subString )
{
    return 
    ( myString.substr( 0, subString.size() ) == subString ) ||
    ( subString.size() < myString.size() && find( myString.substr( 1 ), subString ) );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << find( "Hello World", "World" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << find( "Hello C", "C++" ) << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
false
```

As for your function then it will return true only in the case when the both string have the same length and are equal each other

```
if(myString == substring){
        return true;
    }
```

And in case when myString.length() > substring.length() the function returns nothing

```
else if (myString.length() > substring.length()){
    int start = 1;
    int end = (int) myString.length() - 1;
    string string2 = myString.substr(start, end);
    find(string2, substring); 
}
```

I think you mean

```
    return find(string2, substring);
```

in this code snippet.

**EDIT:** I see that you changed the code of the function in your post. But in any case this code snippet

```
for(int i = 0; i < substring.length() - 1 ; ++i)
{
    if(mystring.at(i) == substring.at(i))
       {
           continue;
       }
    else
    {
        string string2 = mystring.substr(1, mystring.length() - 1);
        return find(string2, substring); 
    }
    return true;
}
```

makes no sense.

Comment: just a question, I just voted your answer as "answered", but why do you use size() instead of length()?  and why does my updated function that iterates one char at a time not work? you have been very helpful, I just still have some confusion.

Comment: @JCoder  length is an alias for member function size of class std::string. So they may be used interchangeably.:) I used size because it is shorter.:)

Comment: @JCoder  As for your second loop then the condition of the loop shall be  i < substring.length()  instead of  i < substring.length()  and return true shall be placed outside the loop. Also in this case you shall remove the preceding comparison of strings.:)

Answer (score 2):

Check this function, it based on your code, with removal of extra code and fix of the errors.

I also changed the signature to get const reference to improve the efficiency.

```
bool find(const string& myString, const string& substring)
{
    if(myString.length() < substring.length()){ 
        return false;
    }
    else if(myString.substr(0,substring.size()) == substring){
        return true;
    }
    else if (myString.length() > substring.length()){
        return find(myString.substr(1), substring); 
    }
    else{
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `return` before the recursive call to `find`. As it stands it falls through to the `return false` at the end.

Also, `if (mystring == substring)` should be checking if `mystring` starts with `substring`, not exact equality.

Comment: There's more than one problem with the code! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is expensive because of the memory copies in substr.

Second, you havent checked for substring length > 0.

Third, the "else if" check for mystring.length > 0 is redundant if you have done the other checks (including substring length > 0).

Now to your core logic. In the recursion your start is never moving, so you are tied to the beginning. What you need to do is start with position 1, and increment start at every recursion, and also extract using substr the substring from "start" to "start + substring.length". That way you start from the beginning, keep moving forward, and check the correct length. You could also start from the end (as you have) and move back, what you would have to do there is: find sart position (end position minus length of substring), and check that the start position is not less than zero before calling the function recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You're just removing the leftmost characters of `myString` and then comparing the rest to your `substring`. Obviously, this is not going to work in a general case, when your `substring` is somewhere in the middle of `myString`.

On each iteration try comparing not the whole `myString`, but rather the first `substring.size()` characters of it. This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Here's what I have so far, but it only returns true if the string
>   begins with the substring.

It also fails for `find("foo", "f")`.

To see why, add some test output to the function:

```
bool find(string myString, string substring)
{
    std::cout << myString << ", " << substring << "\n";
    // ...
}
```

It will print:

```
foo, f
oo, f
o, f
```

You see why this cannot work? You just keep removing the first character, until only the last character is compared with the substring to be found.

But it fails even for `find("foo", "o")`:

```
foo, o
oo, o
o, o
```

That's because of this line:

> ```
>    find(string2, substring);
> ```

You don't return the result of the recursive call.

All things considered, I think you just have the wrong algorithm here. It simply cannot work the way you have written the code.

A few other observations:

> ```
>     int start = 1;
>     int end = (int) myString.length() - 1;
> ```

That's not good style. For historical reasons, a `std::string`'s size is unsigned, and you are using a C-style cast where `static_cast` should be preferred. You should just use `std::string::size_type` here, because it's just an internal piece of implementation code and you gain nothing from casting to `int`.

> ```
>    string string2 = myString.substr(start, end);
> ```

The second argument of `substr` defines the length of the substring, not the index of the last character. `end` sounds like you use the value as the index of the last character. Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr.